# Como guardar el resultado de una consulta de sql server en variables

Tags: sql-server

Perdon por no explicar bien la pregunta. Muchos quieren saber para que es: Es Para un reporte de calcule de costos para un articulo manufacturado, los costos se calculan desde el nivel mas bajo y se van sumando hasta el nivel mas alto. Lo que pasa es que desarrolle esta solucion pero la tengo en Excel VBA, y estoy usando arreglos de memoria. Ahora la quiero portar a SQL. No contre la forma de adjutar una hoja de calculo. Es para un ponche de frutas (imaginario) porque por politicas de la empresa no puedo usar valora reales :-( Estoy mostrando 2 niveles, pero puden ser hasta 10.
Ejemplo:

```
Nivel(1)=0  CostoTotal(1)=0 Articulo(1)="A0"    Descripcion(1)="Bebida sabor Ponche"    Cantidad(1)=1   Fuente(1)="Final"   Tipo(1)=" " Costo(1)=
Nivel(2)=1  CostoTotal(2)=0 Articulo(2)="B1"    Descripcion(2)="Recipiente de Plastico" Cantidad(2)=1   Fuente(2)="Comprado"    Tipo(2)="M" Costo(2)=5
Nivel(3)=1  CostoTotal(3)=0 Articulo(3)="C1"    Descripcion(3)="Tapa de Plastico"   Cantidad(3)=1   Fuente(3)="Comprado"    Tipo(3)="M" Costo(3)=1
Nivel(4)=1  CostoTotal(4)=0 Articulo(4)="D1"    Descripcion(4)="Liquido"    Cantidad(4)=1   Fuente(4)="SubNivel"    Tipo(4)="M" Costo(4)=
Nivel(5)=2  CostoTotal(5)=0 Articulo(5)="E2"    Descripcion(5)="Azucar" Cantidad(5)=0.1 Fuente(5)="Comprado"    Tipo(5)="M" Costo(5)=20
Nivel(6)=2  CostoTotal(6)=0 Articulo(6)="F2"    Descripcion(6)="Otros - No se suman"    Cantidad(6)=1   Fuente(6)="Comprado"    Tipo(6)="O" Costo(6)=10
Nivel(7)=2  CostoTotal(7)=0 Articulo(7)="G2"    Descripcion(7)="Manzana"    Cantidad(7)=0.1 Fuente(7)="Comprado"    Tipo(7)="M" Costo(7)=100
Nivel(8)=2  CostoTotal(8)=0 Articulo(8)="H2"    Descripcion(8)="Pera"   Cantidad(8)=0.1 Fuente(8)="Comprado"    Tipo(8)="M" Costo(8)=80
Nivel(9)=2  CostoTotal(9)=0 Articulo(9)="I2"    Descripcion(9)="Agua"   Cantidad(9)=0.1 Fuente(9)="Comprado"    Tipo(9)="M" Costo(9)=10
```

Se suman los costos del nivel 2 y se vacian en el nivel 1 , luego se calculan los costos del nivel 1 y se vacian en al nivel 0, y este es el costo final.

Hay alguna manera de guardar el esultado de una consulta de SQL server en variables? Como ejemplo: En Basic,se puede hacer algo como:

```
dim Control(100)
dim Fruta(100)
y puedo llenar las variable así:
Control(1)=1
Fruta(1)="Manzana"
Control(2)=2
Fruta(2)="Pera"
... hasta 100
```

Es posible hacer esto usando una consulta en SQL server?

```
select control, fruta from almacen
```

Y que el resultado de la consulta vaya llenando los valores de las variable Control y Fruta??

Comment: Creo que es importante entender que en bases de datos relacionales, estás trabajando con sets de datos, no es lo mismo que "recorrer" los datos guardando en variables. Sería mejor que explicaras cuál es tu objetivo final

Comment: Lo que preguntas requeriría que sql-server tuviera un tipo de dato `ARRAY` o similiar para guardar el resultado completo de una consulta, y no lo tiene. Por consiguiente la respuesta rápida sería: no se puede. Por eso sería bueno tal como te comentó Lamak que explicarás mejor que es lo que buscas hacer.

Comment: Hay algo para "querys recursivos", busca la sentiencia "WITH" y dentro de ella vas a crear dos consultas unidas por el union, la primera es para tu nivel 1 y la segunda es para los niveles dinámicos.

Comment: @JorgeJuárez un CTE no es un query recursivo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer algo como ésto:

```
declare @control nvarchar(100)
, @fruta nvarchar(100)

select @control = control, @fruta = fruta
from almacen
```

Finalmente puedes ver los valores con:

```
select @control as Control, @fruta as Fruta
```

Ya solo deberías pulir tu consulta, en este caso elegiría el primer registro acorde a la consulta y el orden elegido.

Comment: El problema de tu respuesta es que en esas variables van a quedar guardados un único valor por variable. No cada uno de los datos de la tabla

Comment: ¿Cual es la finalidad de almacenarlos en variables?, es decir, ¿cómo los utilizarías?

Comment: No sé si me estás preguntando a mí, pero yo no soy el usuario que posteó la pregunta

Comment: Gracias a todos.. todavía no encuentro la respuesta. Pero si no puedo hacerlo en SQL Server, voy a usar una Hoja De Trabajo de Excel, hacer una conexion ODBC al servidor, hacer la consulta, bajar los datos a la hoja de trabajo y hacer el proceso en la Hoja de Trabajo. Gracias!